How to Remove a Large File from ZFS Snapshots and Reclaim Space?
I have a series of daily ZFS 100Mb snapshots of archive_zp/my_zfs, going back 100 days.  At day 60 (between @ss59%ss60) I had added a 10 GiB sized archive_zp/my_zfs/BIG.iso file, that 10 GiB now appears in the 40 snapshots since, and so retaining the original 10 GiB of archive_zp zpool's space ever since.
I don't want to retain the file BIG.iso in any snapshot, and do want to reclaim the BIG.iso's 10 GiBs space used. However also I do need to retain the other substance (files and daily snapshots etc) in all the 40 daily snapshots since.
My gut feel is that I could follow this path:

zfs clone archive_zp/my_zfs@ss60 my_zfs_clone,
rm archive_zp/my_zfs_clone60/BIG.iso,
zfs promote archive_zp/my_zfs_clone - this retains earlier zpool blocks prior to @ss60.

Then I get a little vague... (to avoid snapshot's UID issues) Do I use a rsync sequence like:

rsync -av --progress /archive_zp/my_zfs/.zfs/snapshot/ss61 /archive_zp/my_zfs_clone
zfs snapshot archive_zp/my_zfs_clone@ss61
etc for @ss62 .. @ss100

Or might I take advantage of zfs replication esp. given BIG.iso was unchanged in ss61%ss100? eg.:

zfs send -I archive_zp/my_zfs@ss61 archive_zp/my_zfs@ss100 | zfs receive archive_zp/my_zfs_clone

With a tidy up at the end:

review archive_zp/my_zfs_clone - then if all OK...
zfs destroy archive_zp/my_zfs
rename archive_zp/my_zfs_clone to archive_zp/my_zfs

Is there a best practice on, or a zfs reclaim tool, to achieve this BIG.iso space recovery?
Maybe a zfs destroy archive_zp/my_zfs/BIG.iso@ss60٪ss100 could do the trick?

so interesting question: "how to get rid of a unwanted file in snapshots?"
Problems:

find affected snapshots
get back the space

"Solutions":

There is a .zfs/snapshots/<snapshots>/<fs-content> where you can find.
assuming you to from 1) a array with all the snapshots, the challenge is to not trigger COW space claims.

2.1) make snapshot writable -> zfs clone <zfspath>@<snapname> <zfspath>/<clonename>
2.2) remove the unwanted stuff from the clone
2.3) remove the snapshot <zfs>@<snapname>
so we see based on my known feature set of zfs, one can reclaim the block space, but you lose in the way that you can not change the snapshots of the original . In short one transforms all snapshots in clones.
Summary: I know no way to do that, what would be needed is e.g. a feature for filtering during zfs-send and zfs-receive, which could modify the target by filtering/dropping item, but even that would lead to at least 2x more storage needed. Writing that you can even thing about an alternative.
Alternative:
As the original plan does not work anyway ending up with 2x space needs, one can just proceed by creating a new <zfspath>, - rsyncing with --exclude - the needed items, taking snapshot again, leading to the same result with the same impact.

Or just use zfs diff described here:
Identifying ZFS Snapshot Differences (zfs diff)
to list the difference between that 60day snapshot and the actual one.
After identifying the location of that BIG.iso file with the above zfs diff command, you can just delete that BIG.iso file in question within that particular snapshot with:
zfs destroy archive_zp/my_zfs@ss60/path/to/BIG.iso


Have you tested your solution?

@z0d1ac ZFS has no such functionality as of 2024/09/06 to destroy a single file inside a snapshot.

touch /home/gentoo/testfile && zfs snapshot  tank/home/gentoo@test && zfs destroy tank/home/gentoo@test/testfile results in could not find any snapshots to destroy; check snapshot names.;
